# PowerShell script does not execute by task scheduler "CylancePROTECT"

Tags: powershell

I try to execute a backup script (`.ps1`) from task scheduler but that execute with error

> CylancePROTECT Script Control has blocked access to this PowerShell script

It works manually.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try Invoking with the -F parameter

Comment: Same happened to me yesterday, with scoop script. Thanks a lot for an info, that it works manually. I created batch file, which I run instead with same behavior.
It's content in first line is "powershell pathToPS1\script.ps1 %*"

Answer (score 0):

It is being blocked by the third-party program [CylancePROTECT](https://www.cylance.com/en-us/platform/products/cylance-protect.html). You will need to speak to whoever manages that to have them unblock it. Most likely the program is blocking scripts being run non-interactively or blocking them from running as whatever user your task is set to use.

Comment: bat file is executed but mot ps1 file why ?